# CSS Transition delay on button Polymer 1.0

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm making a simple custom-button, and I want to add a delay effect to some div's background-colors when the button is clicked. I'm using polymer behaviors (Iron.control.state and Iron.Button.State) for the active states.

Apparently the CSS property of `transition-delay:` when the button is clicked `:host([active])`, doesn't work. The rest works fine.

Here is my simplified code:

```
<dom-module id="my-button">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .button{
      width: 280px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 12px 0px 0px;
    }
    .icon {
      --iron-icon-height: 40px;
      --iron-icon-width: 40px;
      fill: #b4b4b4;
    }
    .tab1, .tab2, .tab3{
      width: 20px;
      height: 50px;
      transition: bacbackground-color .2s ease-out;  /*This Will Animate*/
    }
    :host([active])
      .tab1{
        background-color: #18307a;
        transition-delay: .15s;  /* This Does'nt Work!*/
      }
    :host([active])
      .tab2{
        background-color: #1a35a8;
        transition-delay: .2s;  /* This Does'nt Work!*/
      }
    :host([active])
      .tab3{
        background-color: #1936ce;
        transition-delay: .25s;  /* This Does'nt Work!*/
      }

    :host([active])
      .menu-icon{
        fill: #1936ce;
      }

  </style>

  <template>

    <div class="button layout horizontal center">
      <iron-icon icon="my-icons:icon" class="icon"></iron-icon>
      <div class="flex">{{label}}</div>
      <div class="tab1"></div>
      <div class="tab2"></div>
      <div class="tab3"></div>
    </div>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-button',

      properties: {
        label: String
      },

      behaviors: [
        Polymer.IronControlState,
        Polymer.IronButtonState
      ],

      hostAttributes: {
        role: 'button'
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to apply a `transition` not `transition-delay`. If you are trying to do a `transition-delay`, make sure you also apply a `transition`.

```
:host([active]) .tab1 {
  background-color: #18307a;
  transition: background-color 2s;
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}
```

Update:

You'll want the css transition-delays to be active *before* you switch to the active state.

```
.tab1 { transition-delay: 0.15s; }
.tab2 { transition-delay: 0.20s; }
.tab3 { transition-delay: 0.25s; }
```

Note they're not nested in `:host([active])`.

Comment: I'm aplying the transition with general selection  to 3 classes '.tab1, .tab2, .tab3' but i want to play the transition sequencially on the active state using 'transition-delay' for each tab whit different timing-delay, so the effect look "progressive".
I will experiment with 'animation' and @keyframes  to see if it's better. Thanks anyway =)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. In that case you actually want to stagger the transition-delay on the pre-active selectors. Editing my answer.